# Multithreaded program crashes when dealing with large files

Tags: c

I'm very new to C and I'm struggling with proper memory management and pointer use in a program I wrote.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>


struct argStruct {
    FILE *file;
    int start;
    int end;
};


void processFile(void *input)
{
    struct argStruct params = *(struct argStruct*) input;

//    FILE *textFile = params.file;
    int start = params.start;
    int end = params.end;


    printf("\nTHREAD - Start: %d | End: %d", start, end);

}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *pfile;
    int threadCount = 0, fileSize = 0, divide = 0;


    if (argc > 2)
    {
        pfile = fopen( argv[1], "r");
        threadCount = atoi(argv[2]);

        pthread_t * thread = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)* threadCount);


        fseek(pfile, 0, SEEK_END);
        fileSize= ftell(pfile);
        fseek(pfile, 0, SEEK_SET);


        divide = (fileSize/threadCount);

        struct argStruct arguments;
        arguments.file = pfile;


        for(int i = 0; i < fileSize; i = i + divide) {

            arguments.start = i;
            arguments.end = i+divide;

            struct argStruct *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
            *p = arguments;

            pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, (void *) processFile, p);

        }
        free(thread);
        pthread_exit(NULL);

        fclose(pfile);
        free(thread);

    } else {
        printf("Please enter text file name and number of threads");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Right now, my program is aiming to take a text file and determines how much the text file should be divided up into based on file size and number of threads specified by user input.

Its should then pass the file, and two ints to pthread_create, a starting and stopping point. I'm going to add more functionality later on, but right now I am running into memory issues.

When I run what I have right now on a small to medium size text file, it works as it should. 
A small file with 5 threads has the following output, which is what I'm going for:

```
THREAD - Start: 0 | End: 1724
THREAD - Start: 1724 | End: 3448
THREAD - Start: 3448 | End: 5172
THREAD - Start: 5172 | End: 6896
THREAD - Start: 6896 | End: 8620
THREAD - Start: 8620 | End: 10344
Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, when I run it with a large text file, I get exit code 11 and the error message:
Segmentation fault: 11

When trying to use a debugger, it points me to the line where the threads are being created:

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, (void *) processFile, p);
```

I believe I'm not allocating enough memory for larger files or my pointer use is incorrect, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please write an appropriate title that correctly summarizes your problem. The current title is not useful to understand what the question is about.

Comment: Can you please provide an input file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```c
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, (void *) processFile, p);
```

Here `i` is assumed to be counting threads however looking at the for loop...

```c
for(int i = 0; i < fileSize; i = i + divide) {
```

`i` is actually positions inside the input file and after the first iteration is far outside the range of the `thread` array.

Comment: @ksm You can probably use `i/divide` but I would go the other way: only increment `i` by one and then do `arguments.start=i*divide; arguments.end=(i+1)*divide;`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I [also] would use your second approach, but we need to special case the last thread (e.g.) `arguments.end = (i != (threadCount - 1)) ? (i+1)*divide : fileSize - 1;`